# Utilizar un Windows Form como principal

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen Dia,

Estoy trabajando con Windows Form dentro de C#, el cual estoy trabajando en un modulo para la empresa que comienza asi al momento de inicializar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual este seria el index.

Justo a la derecha superior se encuentra un botón que se llama "examen" en lo cual pretendo que al presionarlo pueda verse lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual se encuentra de otro Windows Form. De aquí parte mi duda lo que yo pretende es que el formulario pueda verse dentro del área blanca, solo tenia la duda si tengo que hacer diferentes Windows Form con el mismo estilo del index, porque el modulo "examen" es uno de los varios que llevara entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de no crear tantos Windows Forms, observe vídeos de controles de usuarios pero no entiendo mucho porque nunca los he manejado, si me pudieran ayudar.

Anexo una foto de lo que pretendo hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Muy buenas, pues tienes dos opciones, o crear controles de usuario, como bien indicas en la pregunta, o puedes usar [aplicaciones de interfaz MDI](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications). Para cualquiera de los dos casos podrás encontrar mucha información y ejemplos. Si necesitas ayuda con alguna parte concreta te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas Gracias ElGerar logre hacerlo con MDI y con los controles de usuario. Saludos!

Comment: Si la aplicación va a ser mediana-grande, yo te recomendaría muchisimo que aprendieras y aplicaras patrones de diseño,  sino ahi te quiero ver cuando ya tengas muchísimo código en code behind entremezclado con controles y quieras dar mantenimiento a tu aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) En tu formulario principal debes marcarlo como `MDIContainer`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2)Debes agregar un `menuStrip` para mantener un menu en tu formulario principal, y dentro de el agregar tu boton.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3) En el evento click del boton en tu menu invocamos al form, maximizado.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2
              {
                MdiParent = this,
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
              };
              newMDIChild.Show();
        }
```

El resultado seria :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias de verdad justo como lo quería. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza las propiedades de MDI container y MDI Parent

con esas la "form Principal" se convierte en un contenedor para todas las nuevas formas que crees donde el "mdi parent" sea la form principal

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda!.

Answer (score 2):

Buen día!

**1.** Inicialmente vas a tener que crear los nuevos Forms los cuales quieras que estén contenidos en el Form index *(En este caso sería el form Examen)*.

**2.** Podes utilizar *MDI Containers* que funcionaran como Forms secundarios o hijos del Form principal.

- Se creará una nueva instancia del *FormChild* que en tu caso será *Examen* dentro de tu Form index.

Te dejo un breve ejemplo, espero que te sirva!

Saludos!

```c#
private void btnExamen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    Form FormChild = new Form();
    FormChild.MdiParent = this;
    FormChild.Show();
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ivan! Convine las lineas que me pasaste con otras y ya pude!